# how stop the android edit text box refreshing

Tags: android

i'm new to android ,I am try to get my current location address.my code is working but value of the text box is refreshing time to time. how i stop it...

this is my code..

public class MylocMainActivity extends Activity {

```
 String lat="", lon="";
    String ret= "" ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myloc_main);


      //button click done
    Button btnLocation = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_done);
    btnLocation.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            location(); 
            Log.d("OnClick","Passed");
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.myloc_main, menu);
    return true;
}


 public void location()
    {
        // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) MylocMainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // Define a listener that responds to location updates
        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
                lat = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
                lon = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location);
                tv.setText("Your Location is:" + lat + "--" + lon);
                tv.setText(GetAddress(lat, lon));
                Intent i = new Intent(MylocMainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("clist",ret.toString());
                startActivity(i);

            }


            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        };
        // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

    }


    // get the address 
    public String GetAddress(String lat, String lon)
    {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);

        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lon), 1);
            if(addresses != null) {
                Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("Address:\n");
                for(int i=0; i<returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                }
                ret = strReturnedAddress.toString();
            }
            else{
                ret = "No Address returned!";
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            ret = "Can't get Address!";
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

}

........Main Activity class.............

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent startbuttonintent = getIntent();

    String conlist = null;

    conlist = startbuttonintent.getStringExtra("clist");
    TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.family_Text);
    name.setText(conlist);



     Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_location);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MylocMainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Your textview is probably refreshing because the location has changed, notable or not. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Each time the location changes it changes the content of the textview although the content might not have actually changed due to number precision.
Try this or something similar with setting the textview:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
{
    // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
    lat = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
    lon = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location);
    if(!tv.getText().equals(GetAddress(lat, lon)))
    {
        tv.setText("Your Location is:" + lat + "--" + lon);
        tv.setText(GetAddress(lat, lon));
    }
    Intent i = new Intent(MylocMainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("clist",ret.toString());
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the helping... i put this code for remove location updates  locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);                       it is work fine..

Answer (score 0):

you could store the Location from onLocationChanged in an Location value (mLocation).
every time the location changes you check

```
if (mLocation != null) { // do something }
```